# Is there a way to choose the audio port for a particular program in a cpu with two audio outputs?

Tags: audio, operating-system, cpu, audio-capture

I have two audio outputs in my cpu. One is meant for speakers and the other for headphones.I want to create a program in which I can choose which program is allowed to play sound in which port. So that I can put headphones in one port, and play something on the speaker connected to another port. Currently the speaker in back port goes off if I connect earphones to the other port.

PS : Don't really know which tags to choose for this. Please suggest the right tags.

Comment: Too broad, specify at least the OS and the programming languages you are able to use. It looks like you'll need to explore the concept of `audio mixer` and you want to write a mixer `plugin`

Comment: I am currently using windows 8.1. If you could suggest something using java it would be great. I am also open for python, or even c, c++ (I am looking at JNI). Anything. Tell me the approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what would be the correct final solution, haven't worked with the sound APIs involving other applications (manipulating sound output options of a 3rd party closed-source application) and I'm not sure if it is generally supported scenario. But some tips to get you started might be:

- **1.** web search queries - that is what I used to "quickly" find the other tips:

  - `application specific audio output`
  - `windows open source application specific audio output`
  - `windows audio mixer api`
  - `open source configurable audio mixer for windows`
- [MSDN: Windows → Dev Center - Desktop → Audio Mixer Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756706(v=vs.85).aspx) - this is probably the basic stuff you should learn, but probably the most low-level with steep learning curve
- [Super User: Assigning programs to specific audio outputs in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/73921/assigning-programs-to-specific-audio-outputs-in-windows-7) - this is probably some ready-to-buy solution
- [SoundSwitch](https://soundswitch.codeplex.com/) - open source, something to study/tweak - "*With SoundSwitch you just configure once between which Playback devices you want to toggle and then you can press Ctrl+Alt+F11 to toggle automatically*"
- [JACK Audio Connection Kit](http://jackaudio.org/applications/) - open source - "*JACK on Windows is a multi-purpose application that connects audio and MIDI using the Windows system drivers... It connects (OUTPUT) to those audio drivers using the PortAudio project*"